# matchedgeometryeffect doesn't work as expected

Tags: swiftui

What do I want : Have a smooth animation between two views ( stack of cards and list of cards) so I used `matchedgeometryeffect` in SwiftUI but there is something wrong with my code that I couldn't fix.

I used `same ID` for two views also determine the `isSource` property.

```
   struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showCardByList = false
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    @State var cards : [Card] = [
        Card(color: .green),
        Card(color: .blue),
        Card(color: .pink),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Change")
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        showCardByList.toggle()
                    }
                }
            
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
       
                if showCardByList {
                    
                    List(cards: $cards, namespace: namespace)
                    
                } else {
                
                    Stack(cards: $cards, namespace: namespace)
                        .padding(.top,150)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .top)
    }
}

struct Card : Identifiable {
   
    var id = UUID()
    var color: Color
}
```

Stack view:

```
struct Stack: View {
    
    @Binding var cards : [Card]
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    func offset(index : Int) -> CGFloat {
        switch index  {
        case 0:
            return -50
        case 1:
            return -80
        case 2:
            return -110
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func getIndex(card : Card) -> Int {
        if let index = cards.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) {
            return index
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(cards,id: \.id) { card in
                    ZStack {
                        card.color.cornerRadius(20)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: namespace,isSource: true)
                    }
                    .offset(y: offset(index: getIndex(card: card)))
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 210, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

List View:

```
struct List: View {
    
    @Binding var cards : [Card]
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 50) {
                    ForEach(cards,id: \.id) { card in
                        ZStack {
                           card.color.cornerRadius(20)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: namespace,isSource: false)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark both of your `.matchedGeometryEffect`s with `isSource: true`.  The two views are never on the screen at the same time, and each serves as the source when switching to the other.

Change:

```
.matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: namespace,isSource: false)
```

to:

```
.matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: namespace,isSource: true)
```

To address the fading in/out of the views, add `.transition(.slide)` to the two views:

```
if showCardByList {
    
    List(cards: $cards, namespace: namespace)
        .transition(.slide)
    
    
} else {

    Stack(cards: $cards, namespace: namespace)
        .transition(.slide)
        .padding(.top,150)
}
```

*Note:* The documentation doesn't say that you can't have two views marked with `isSource: true`, just that you shouldn't have two such views on screen at the same time.

---

Here it is running in the simulator:

[image: Demo running in the simulator]

Comment: Thanks for your help, would you please take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927667/why-do-i-need-two-matchedgeometryeffect-for-this-situation